# How do I merge rows while also moving columns to the merged row?

Tags: r

Hello everyone and thanks for reading my question.

I have the following in R:

```
**type, status, count**
human, living, 36
human, living, 57
human, dead, 43
mouse, living, 4
mouse, dead 8
```

What I want to do is merge the rows based on 'type' (so 'type' would be exclusive) and then move the contents of 'status' and 'count' to the merged row and add some symbols as shown below:

```
**type, status, count**
human, living = "36, 57", dead = "43"
mouse, living = "4", dead = "8"
```

I did manage to merge the rows in R (sort of) but I cannot figure out how to move the status and count to the merged row and lay them out as shown.

I don't have to use R but I thought R was the most suitable way of doing this but I could use anything to get the job done.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Edit: This is the final solution which worked great (thanks loads to gersht):

```
rm(list=ls()); 

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table("D:/test.csv", header = TRUE, sep=",")

df <- df %>%
    group_by(type, status) %>% 
    mutate(count = paste(count, collapse = ", ")) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    distinct() %>% 
    spread(status, count) %>% 
    mutate(dead = paste("dead = ", dead),
           living = paste("living = ", living))


write.table(df, col.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Could you read with `read.csv` first and `spread`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm quite new to R.  Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return a dataframe with correct values, more or less. You can change column order and column names as needed:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    group_by(type, status) %>% 
    mutate(count = paste(count, collapse = ", ")) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    distinct() %>% 
    spread(status, count) %>% 
    mutate(dead = paste("dead = ", dead),
           living = paste("living = ", living))

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  type  dead       living          
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>           
1 human dead =  43 living =  36, 57
2 mouse dead =  8  living =  4
```

I've simply grouped by `type` and `status` so I can then collapse the values of `count` into a single string using `mutate()`. I use `ungroup()` as good practice, but it isn't strictly necessary.

This creates some duplicates, which I remove with `distinct()`. I then use the `spread()` function to move `living` and `dead` to their own columns, and then I use `mutate` again to add strings `"living = "` and `"dead = "` to their respective columns.

### data

```r
structure(list(type = c("human", "human", "human", "mouse", "mouse"
), status = c("living", "living", "dead", "living", "dead"), 
    count = c(36, 57, 43, 4, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: This sounds perfect but I tried it and it doesn't seem to do anything.  I added this to the start: df <- read.csv("D:/test.csv", strip.white=TRUE); to get my CSV file in and then I click Source in RStudio to run the script.  That produces df.  i click that to view it and it looks exactly same as my original CSV with no merged rows or anything.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Jstation yes you need to import a dataframe first. If the data is very different from the above then there is a good chance that it won't work. You will probably have to modify things slightly, or you can gave us a sample of your actual data.

Comment: I'm just going off the exact example I am showing here.  I'm using the CSV file at the top of my question and i copy/pasted your script into a new R file.  The only thing I added was df <- read.csv("D:/test.csv", strip.white=TRUE); to the top of the file and write.table(df) to the bottom to print it.  The output looks identical the input though.  If I remove strip.white=TRUE, I get an error Error 'in paste("dead = ", dead) : object 'dead' not found'

Comment: I tried adding your structure to the top of the file (instead of read.csv) using this: df <- structure... etc but no change, the output is still not changed.  Am I reading the file in incorrectly with df <- read.csv(file)?

Comment: I added your suggested code as an edit to my original question so you can see exactly what my R file contains.  The CSV file I'm using only contains the table shown at the top of my question.  Thanks.

Comment: I solved it by using this df <- df %>% instead of just df %>%, it was a very silly omission but I'm quite new to R.  I have marked your answer.  Thanks loads for your help. :)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out @Jstation. The silly mistakes are the ones that get you, but we all make them. Some advice for the future: You can use `dput(df)` to generate `structure(…)` like I use above. You can then include that in your questions so we have a better idea of what your data looks like.

Comment: That's a great suggestion, @gersht, I will make a note of that. :)